# GameLogic.CROSS not working - "Expected resource of type id"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make tictactoe app from [this](http://hubpages.com/technology/tictactoe#) tutorial. I have problem with GameLogic.CROSS in switchTurn in GameActivity.java:

```
private void switchTurn(int position) {
        if (mTurn == TURN.CIRCLE) {
            mBlocks[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
            mBlocks[position].setId(GameLogic.CIRCLE);
            mTurn = TURN.CROSS;
            mDisplay.setText("CROSS's turn");
        } else {
            mBlocks[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
            mBlocks[position].setId(GameLogic.CROSS);
            mTurn = TURN.CIRCLE;
            mDisplay.setText("CIRCLE's turn");
        }
        mBlocks[position].setEnabled(false);
        mStatusCounter++;
        if (GameLogic.isCompleted(position + 1, mBlocks)) {
            mDisplay.setText(GameLogic.sWinner + " won");
            displayStick(GameLogic.sSet);
            disableAll();
        }else if (mStatusCounter==9){
            mDisplay.setText("DRAW. Try again");
        }
    }
```

Android Studio 2.0 display error on GameLogic.CROSS:

> Expected resource of type id

Comment: Is it an error, or just a warning?

Comment: an error. I have only that 1, and my app can't be build

Comment: Well, that's kinda odd. I'd figure you get the same error for `CIRCLE`, then, too. There might be an option in your IDE to allow arbitrary IDs. Failing that, you can create your own IDs to use in place of `GameLogic.CIRCLE` and `GameLogic.CROSS`. Have a look at [this developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id). You would then use something like `R.id.circle` and `R.id.cross` in your code. Or, you could refactor the example to use the `ImageView`s' tags instead of IDs, and keep the `GameLogic` constants.

Comment: GameLogic.CIRCLE does NOT return error to me

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it was odd. Well, I gave you three possible options. Try 'em out.